# How to save duplicate files with sequential numbers after the file name?

Tags: python, file, while-loop, barcode

I am trying to write a little program to generate barcodes for my products. I have two variables, one for the barcode, and one for the quantity. When the program as the user how many barcodes they want to be saved, it just saves one file and overwrites them. If the user enters more than one I want the file to be saved with the barcode name followed by sequential numbers. For example: `barcode.svg`, `barcode(1).svg`, `barcode(2).svg`
etc.

I tried writing an if-statement saying if the quantity was 1 then save 1, and then if the quantity is 2, then save two files. But it just kept overwriting the same file, this idea seems way too manual and I am sure I need to be doing with while loops (which I tried) to get this to go correctly.

This is my current code:

```
# import EAN13 from barcode module
from barcode import EAN14

# Make sure to pass the number as string
number = input("Enter the barcode ")
quantity = input("Enter the quantity ")

# Now, let's create an object of EAN13
# class and pass the number
my_code = EAN14(number)

if quantity == 1:
    my_code.save(number)

if quantity == 2:
    my_code.save(number)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use a simple for loop to perform this task. Let me show you how you can do it.

```
from barcode import EAN14
number = input("Enter the barcode: ")
quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
my_code = EAN14(number)

for i in range(quantity):
    if i == 0:
        filename = f"{number}.svg"
    else:
        filename = f"{number}({i}).svg"
    my_code.save(filename)
```

Comment: You could put the 0 case outside the loop and use `range(1,quantity)` as a minor improvement.